# Replace all code on Bluemix web IDE

Tags: git, ibm-cloud, devops

I have been working on an application primarily using a local copy of the git repository which I push regularly to the git repository associated with my Bluemix application.

The Web IDE has fallen out of synch and I would prefer to replace all the data rather than trying to fix discrepancies.

What is the easiest way to fully replace the local (Web IDE) branch with the remote (hub.jazz.net) repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does Force Fetch (you'll see it when you click the arrow beside Fetch) sync your web IDE's local repo successfully?

Comment: Thanks. That worked.  I had tried it before without success but as I didn't know I was on the right track I hadn't push.

It seems that the issue was that I had some outstanding changes (listed on the right hand side).  I just discarded them all, and then did the force fetch and it all worked!

Thanks